# How do I change a field without updating my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 different tables: A table that gives me `SWIFT/BIC` codes for banks and a table that is the `US FEDERAL ACH DIRECTORY` that doesn't give me SWIFTS. The Bank Name in the `SWIFT` code table looks like `"NBT Bank National Association"` while the name in my `FED ACH DIRECTORY` looks like `"NBT BANK NA"`.

I was pondering about using logic in my INNER JOINs; however, I feel like if I were to come back to this, that would be really hard to decode.

How would I go about making that view SOLEY for that logic? Then Would I then combine it to my other views on Bank Name? This is helping me profile data.

Edit: NBT BANK NA is only 1 example. I have so many different banks where the names do not align, but they are clearly the same bank.

Comment: Add an ID for them , and join using the id

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, and not meant as an answer.

Go to https://banks.data.fdic.gov/docs/ and take a peek at BULK FILES

Between the INSTITUTIONS and LOCATIONS files, you may be able to get enough information to link or map the SWIFT codes.

They actually do a good job in maintaining active and inactive institutions as well as the proper names.